# Combinations of a variadic list of arbitrary types

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'd like to get a cartesian product of all the possible string-value pairs which are input in a variadic list of arguments and obtain a map `M` as,

```
using M = std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any>;
template<typename ...Args>
std::vector<M> combinations(const std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Args>> &...args) {
// ... ??
}
```

A possible input is

```
std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> v1 = {"A", {"x","y","z"}};
std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>> v2 = {"B", {1,2,3}};
std::pair<std::string, std::vector<double>> v3 = {"C", {0.1,0.2,0.3}};

auto m1 = combinations(v1,v2) // a vector consisting of 9 maps. E.g., m1[0] = {{"A","x"},{"B",1}} etc...
auto m2 = combinations(v1,v2,v3) // a vector consisting of 27 maps. E.g., m2[0] = {{"A","x"},{"B",1},{"C",0.1}} etc...
```

`m1` (to be explicit)

```
m1[0] : {{"A","x"},{"B",1}}
m1[1] : {{"A","x"},{"B",2}}
m1[2] : {{"A","x"},{"B",3}}
m1[3] : {{"A","y"},{"B",1}}
m1[4] : {{"A","y"},{"B",2}}
m1[5] : {{"A","y"},{"B",3}}
m1[6] : {{"A","z"},{"B",1}}
m1[7] : {{"A","z"},{"B",2}}
m1[8] : {{"A","z"},{"B",3}}
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to use `std::any`/`boost::any` here since we can figure out the exact types.

For example, `m1` will be a:

```cpp
std::vector< std::tuple< std::pair<std::string, std::string>,
                         std::pair<std::string, int> > >;
```

Here's one way:

- In `combinations` I deduce the `tuple` type to store in the resulting `vector` and call `xprod` passing all the `pair`s on with an `index_sequence`.
- From these the cross product will be created in the function `xprod`. I create an array of `pair<size_t, size_t>` for the indices in each `vector`. `idxlim[].first` holds the current index, and `idxlim[].second` holds each vector's `size()`. To step the combined index value over all the `vector`s, I use this:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
bool step_index(std::array<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, N>& idxlim) {    
    for (size_t i = N; i--;) {
        auto&[idx, lim] = idxlim[i];
        if (++idx != lim) return true;
        idx = 0;
    }
    return false; // reached the end
}
```

The `xprod` function receives the `pair`s and creates `idxlim` which contains the current index and the limit for each `vector` and just loops through all combinations, populating the resulting `vector`, `rv`, as it goes:

```cpp
template <class T, size_t... I, class... P>
auto xprod(std::index_sequence<I...>, const P&... pairs) {
    std::vector<T> rv;
    std::array<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, sizeof...(P)> idxlim{
        {{0, pairs.second.size()}...}
    };

    do {
        rv.emplace_back(T{{pairs.first, pairs.second[ idxlim[I].first ]}...});
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                         std::string        the "any" type
    } while(step_index(idxlim));

    return rv;
}
```

The "magic" in `T{{pairs.first, pairs.second[ idxlim[I].first ]}...}` is that it's a *parameter expansion* over `I...` (think horizontally) and `I...` is supplied by creating an `index_sequence` from the entry function (se below). It's not *one* pair. It's all of them (keep thinking horizontally):

It'll be expanded to these `emplace_back`s:

```
T{{"A", "x"}, {"B", 1}}
T{{"A", "x"}, {"B", 2}}
T{{"A", "x"}, {"B", 3}}
T{{"A", "y"}, {"B", 1}}
T{{"A", "y"}, {"B", 2}}
T{{"A", "y"}, {"B", 3}}
T{{"A", "z"}, {"B", 1}}
T{{"A", "z"}, {"B", 2}}
T{{"A", "z"}, {"B", 3}}
```

Entry function:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
auto combinations(const std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Ts>>&... args) {
    using tt = std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, Ts>...>;

    return xprod<tt>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}, args...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d4h8GPbzx)